# Ler uma string separada por vírgula

Tags: c, string, arquivo, stream-de-arquivos, stream

Minha leitura foi estabelecida até a virgula, porém ele está lendo todo campo 
até o fim de linha quando lê a string. O código é lido corretamente, porém apenas no código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct setorEletronicos {
    int codigo;
    char descricao[100];
    int altura;
    int largura;
    int profundidade;
    float preco;
    int estoque;
    char cor[100];
} ;


int main() {
    int i = 0;
    FILE *arquivo;
    struct setorEletronicos eletro[50];

    if ((arquivo = fopen("eletro.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo.\n");
    } else {
        while (!feof(arquivo)) {

            fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]", &eletro[i].codigo);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%s[^,]", eletro[i].descricao);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]", &eletro[i].altura);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]", &eletro[i].largura);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]", &eletro[i].profundidade);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%f[^,]", &eletro[i].preco);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]", &eletro[i].estoque);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%s[^\n]", eletro[i].cor);
            i++;

        }
        fclose(arquivo);
    }

    int aux;
    for (aux = 0; aux < i; aux++) {
        printf("%d \n", eletro[aux].codigo);
        printf("%s \n\n", eletro[aux].descricao);
    }
    return (0);


}
```

arquivo eletro.txt

```
100,Geladeira,180,90,89,1200.00,4,branca
101,Geladeira,180,90,89,1200.00,2,prata
102,Aspirador,30,50,60,149.99,5,vermelho
103,Aspirador,30,50,60,149.99,3,azul
104,Ar Condicionado 18000BTU,50,100,40,2967.00,13,branco
105,Ar Condicionado 9000BTU,50,80,40,1299.00,10,branco
106,TV LCD 42,80,110,15,2500.00,25,preto
105,Forno Eletrico com Microondas,39.2,52.7,0.48,1688.39,7,prata
106,Lavadora de Roupas 1Kg,46,32,32.9,435.00,1,branco
107,Lavadora de Roupas 10Kg,146,70,72.5,959.00,2,branco
108,Radio CD MP3,12.2,34.1,23.6,199.99,100,preto
109,Antena de TV Externa,16.2,118.5,6.5,199.00,5,cinza
110,TV 29 Slim,70,85,65,599.99,3,preta
```

Comment: possível duplicata de [Ler dados de arquivos separados por vírgulas em C](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42585/ler-dados-de-arquivos-separados-por-v%c3%adrgulas-em-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema como o amigo falou é que o ponteiro parava na vírgula e trancava lá até dar ir para a próxima linha com o \n e acontecia tudo de novo. 
Resolvi isso com fseek, segue código de resolução.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct setorEletronicos {
    int codigo;
    char descricao[100];
    int altura;
    int largura;
    int profundidade;
    float preco;
    int estoque;
    char cor[100];
};

struct setorEletronicos eletro[50]; //declara o struct


int le_arquivo();
int main() {
    int cont = 0; // número de aparelhos lido 

    cont = le_arquivo(); 

    return (0);
}

/*
 * função não recebe argumentos
 * le os arquivos e salva na struct
 * para não ler a vírgula pula um 1 byte com f_seek
 * toda vez que chega na mesma, tem como retorno o
 * número de aparelhos lido
 */
int le_arquivo(){
    int i = 0;
    FILE *arquivo;
    if ((arquivo = fopen("eletro.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo.\n");
    } else {
        while (!feof(arquivo)) {

            fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]", &eletro[i].codigo);
            fseek(arquivo, +1, SEEK_CUR);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%[^,]*c", eletro[i].descricao);
            fseek(arquivo, +1, SEEK_CUR);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]", &eletro[i].altura);
            fseek(arquivo, +1, SEEK_CUR);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]", &eletro[i].largura);
            fseek(arquivo,+1,SEEK_CUR);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]", &eletro[i].profundidade);
            fseek(arquivo,+1,SEEK_CUR);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%f[^,]", &eletro[i].preco);
            fseek(arquivo,+1,SEEK_CUR);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]", &eletro[i].estoque);
            fseek(arquivo,+1,SEEK_CUR);
            fscanf(arquivo, "%[^\n]*c", eletro[i].cor);
            i++;

        }
        i--;
        fclose(arquivo);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Um erro visível no código é com a leitura da descrição:

```
fscanf(arquivo, "%s[^,]", eletro[i].descricao[50]);
```

O que você deve passar para o `fscanf` é um ponteiro para onde armazenar a string lida. Mas como argumento você passou um quinquagésimo primeiro elemento de um array. Meramente passe o próprio array.

Além disso deve omitir o `s` do especificador. Caso contrário estará lendo uma string (a linha toda) seguida pelos caracteres `[^,]`. Use, assim:

```
fscanf(arquivo, "%[^,]", eletro[i].descricao);
```

Comment: já melhorou, mas agora ele coloca toda linha dentro da string ... ao invés de parar de ler na vírgula.

Comment: Remova o `s`, o correto é apenas `%[^,]`.

Comment: apenas das strings ou de todas váriaveis ?

Comment: Para esses basta ler um número mesmo. `%d`